# Scipy ifft gives different results with seemingly identical input

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

Why would xcorr and xcorr2 be quite different here?  M1 and M2 are numpy matrices.  M1.shape[0] = M2.shape[0]. xcorr is what I would expect with this operation, but xcorr2 is something totally different and has imaginary numbers. xcorr does not have imaginary numbers.

```
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft

xcorr = np.zeros((M1.shape[0],M1.shape[1],M2.shape[1]))  
xcorr2 = xcorr.copy()

N = M1.shape[1]
for i in range(N):
    V = M1[:,i][:,None]
    xcorr[:,:,i] = ifft(fft(M2,axis = 0) * fft(np.flipud(V), axis = 0) ,axis = 0)

for i in range(N):
    V = M1[:,i][:,None]
    xcorr2[:,:,i] = fft(M2,axis = 0) * fft(np.flipud(V), axis = 0)        
xcorr2 = ifft(xcorr2, axis = 0)
```

Comment: What are the values in M1 and M2, because for me, with random real M1 and M2 the imaginary component of xcorr2 is 0 everywhere

Comment: Thanks Nin17.  M1 and M2 are real and roughly z-scored statistics along each column. Do you find that xcorr and xcorr2 give effectively identical results?  I will try your simulated M1/M2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving `xcorr` and `xcorr2` `dtype=complex`.

```
xcorr = np.zeros((M1.shape[0],M1.shape[1],M2.shape[1]), dtype=complex)  
xcorr2 = xcorr.copy()
```

According to scipy docs, the output from both fft and ifft is a complex ndarray.

You create `xcorr` and `xcorr2` with np.zeros(), so it'll have a default dtype of `float64`.

Putting the output from fft into the xcorr2 will result in a cast of `complex` to `float64`, that results in the imaginary part being discarded.

When you feed xcorr2 into ifft() it has no imaginary part, so you get a different result.

The cast is also why you don't see the imaginary part in xcorr.

Comment: you spelt complex wrong in the code snippet

Comment: @Nin17 - thanks, I'm too used to the IDE filling it in for me.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you pcoates! I'll just elaborate in case anyone finds it helfpul.  for real x and y:   ifft(fft(x*y)) will give real numbers.  But by removing the imaginary values before taking the ifft (in the xcorr2 version of my code), it gives an erroneous result, which is complex.